# Setting specific permission in amazon s3 boto bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have a bucket called 'ben-bucket' inside that bucket I have multiple files.
I want to be able to set permissions for each file URL.
I'm not too sure but I'm assuming if I wanted URL for each file inside a bucket.
My URL would be like this?

```
https://ben-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/<file_name>
```

So basically, I want to set a public access to that URL. How would I do it? 
I tried this and it doesn't work

```
    bucket = s3.Bucket('ben-bucket').Object('db.sqlite')
    bucket.BucketAcl('public-read')
    print bucket_acl
```

The code provided. db.sqlite is one of the files inside my bucket ben-bucket The code doesn't work. I want to be able to access the following URL publicly

```
https://ben-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/db.sqlite
```

The code I provided doesn't set the permission to public-read.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**By default, all objects in Amazon S3 are private.** You can then add permissions so that people can access your objects. This can be done via:

- **Access Control List** permissions on individual objects
- A **Bucket Policy** that grants wide-ranging access based on path, IP address, referrer, etc
- **IAM Users and Groups** that grant permissions to Users with AWS credentials
- **Pre-Signed URLs**

If you wish to grant public access to your entire bucket, the simiplest option is to create a **Bucket Policy** like this (from [Bucket Policy Examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)]:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you wish to grant public access only to a **sub-directory** *within* the bucket, use:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/PATH/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Yes, you could also set the permissions on each individual file. The code for that would be:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Bucket('ben-bucket').Object('db.sqlite')
object.Acl().put(ACL='public-read')
```

Reference: [Boto3 S3 access controls](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrations3.html#access-controls)